# Parse the result of a python call with Node.js

Tags: javascript, python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse the result of my python call with `JSON.parse` . I provide here only the result of my python script (the dictionary).

python script

```
import json 

mydict =    {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "licensePlate" : "O XXX YYY",
  "year" : 1964,
  "insured": {
                'lastname' : 'Snow', 
                'firstname' : 'John', 
                'adress' : 'Holiday street, 4 - Paradise'
             }
}
myjsonlist = json.dumps(mydict, indent = 4) 

print(myjsonlist)
```

my javascript calls the python script and tries to parse the result(= the dictionary from python). The goal is to be able to use this dictionary in javascript. In other words, I would like to extract in javascript the brand  of the car like `brandCar = resut.brand` .

```
//Import express.js module and create its variable.
const express=require('express');
const app=express();

//Import PythonShell module.
const {PythonShell} =require('python-shell');

//Router to handle the incoming request.

//Here are the option object in which arguments can be passed for the python_test.js.
let options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
    scriptPath: '/mnt/c/Users/xxxxx/javascript/' //If you are having python script in same folder, then it's optional.
    //args: ['xxxx'] //An argument which can be accessed in the script using sys.argv[1]
};


PythonShell.run('pythonscript.py', options, function (err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    // result is an array consisting of messages collected
    //during execution of script.
    console.log('result: ', result.toString());

    console.log(JSON.parse(result[0]));
});
```

In the console, i have this as error message and result

```
result:  {,    "brand": "Ford",,    "model": "Mustang",,    "licensePlate": "O XXX YYY",,    "year": 1964,,    "insured": {,        "lastname": "Snow",,        "firstname": "John",,        "adress": "Holiday street, 4 - Paradise",    },}
undefined:1
{

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /mnt/c/Users/xxxxx/javascript/test2.js:62:19
    at PythonShell._endCallback (/mnt/c/Users/xxxxx/javascript/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:254:20)
    at terminateIfNeeded (/mnt/c/Users/xxxxx/javascript/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:209:39)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/xxxxx/javascript/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:182:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:282:12)
```

can you help me with this? I work with Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10, I don't know if this information is relevant or not...

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(result.join('\n'))`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved my issue by

1)
in the python script, I print the dictionary without converting it into a json object. When python is called in javascript it returns a string like below

`result:  {'brand': 'Ford', 'model': 'Mustang', 'licensePlate': 'O XXX YYY', 'year': 1964, 'insured': {'lastname': 'Snow', 'firstname': 'John', 'adress': 'Holiday street, 4 - Paradise'}}`

this string contains single quotes.

2)
In javascript, I replace all single quotes with double quotes for parsing this string to a json object.

```
let parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.join('\n')));
parsedData = parsedData.replace(/'/g, `"`); // replace the quote by the double quotes for parsing the string to a JSON object.
parsedData = JSON.parse(parsedData);
```